# add_dll_directory to path where toto.pyd is but error "No module named toto" at execution of python script

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, pybind11

I use 64 bits python 3.11.4. I coded a toto.pyd with pybind11 (last commit version) in C++. I call a function from this library in a python script. When the library pyd file is in the same folder as the python script, no problem, the code runs as expected. If I move the library file `toto.pyd` to `C:\path\to\toto` for instance, add

```
import os
os.add_dll_directory(r"C:\path\to\toto")
```

in my script before the `import toto` line and execute the python script I surprisingly have a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toto'` error at the `import toto` line in my python script.

(This happens btw independently of the fact that `C:\path\to\toto` is in the `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH` or not.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nothing made my day except :

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\path\to\toto")
```

With that I don't even need to `add_dll_directory` anything anymore.